# Why would my function definition start to throw a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coin-change

To start, I'm a beginner when it comes to working with python. I'm writing a function for the coin-change problem, with additional constraints (find the best way to pay given a list of the amount of each coin type and their value).

The function was working fine and I was almost done when suddenly statements at the start of my function were causing syntax errors. I hadn't been editing these at all as they'd worked, I was sorting out the last few kinks when it happened.

I've pasted the start of my function, note change(*amount*) will return the most appropriate way to pay *amount*. 
Can anyone suggest why this would start presenting a syntax error when it hadn't done so on many previous tests?

```
def pay_with_coins(amount, pocket):
    change_otpt = change(amount)
    import copy
    amount = amount*100 #puts amount in pennies
    original_pocket = copy.deepcopy(pocket)
    original_amount = copy.deepcopy(amount)
    change_amount = copy.deepcopy(amount)
    original_pocket2 = copy.deepcopy(original_pocket)
    original_amount2 = (copy.deepcopy(original_amount)
    coins = [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]    #syntax error 1
    output = [0 for i in range(9)]      #syntax error 2
    ##find pocket value
    def value(pocket):
        value = 0
        for i in range(8):
            value += (pocket[i]*coins[i])
        return value
    pocket_val = value(pocket)
    #print("pocket value is:", pocket_val)

    ##easy case: is there enough money to pay (pocket value less than)
    if pocket_val < amount:
        print('False')
        return False

    ##checking if change() can give a suitable answer########
    count = 0 #variable to check how indexes in change_otpt are within pocket
    for i in range (8):
        if change_otpt[i] <= pocket[i]:
            count += 1
    if count == 8:#i.e output of change() is contained within pocket
        change_otpt.append(0)
    elif:
        change_otpt = [0 for i in range(8)]
    change_used = sum(change_otpt) #how many coins did this method use?
    print('change method returned: ', change_otpt)
    for i in range(7):
        change_amount -= change_otpt[i]*coins[i]
    print('change_amount is',change_amount)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 2):

You've got an extra opening parenthesis on line 9.

```
 ...
 8: original_pocket2 = copy.deepcopy(original_pocket)
 9: original_amount2 = (copy.deepcopy(original_amount)
                       ^ remove this parenthesis here
10: coins = [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]    #syntax error 1
11: output = [0 for i in range(9)]      #syntax error 2
...
```

Comment: The parenthesis is redundant. The unclosed leading `(` should just be removed

Comment: Note: Whenever there is a line with a `SyntaxError` where the line is, on its own, obviously correct, the problem is always because you either have busted indentation, or more commonly, an unclosed set of paired delimiters on a previous line (parentheses, brackets, braces, triple quotes, etc.).

Comment: thank you! I was looking through it for ages trying to see if I'd made a silly mistake like that. really appreciate it